# Doctrine leftJoin entity is not a child of the main entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, left-join, doctrine-query

I have huge query with many leftJoins. All the leftJoin, except of one, is associated in the entities. The one, which does not gets every time an own entry, if I use the array hydration mode.

Basically, I am using Shopware and this query is part of a plugin. However, every referenced Entity, except of my own, can be found at the Shopware GitHub repo: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.3/engine/Shopware/Models/Order/Order.php

My query in my repository:

```
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select([
    'orders',
    'details',
    'payment.id',
    'payment.name',
    'payment.description',
    'payment.action',
    'payment.pluginId',
    'paymentInstances',
    'shipping',
    'billing',
    'billingCountry',
    'shippingCountry',
    'paymentPayPal',
    'paymentStatus',
]);

$builder->from('Shopware\Models\Order\Order', 'orders');
$builder->leftJoin('orders.details', 'details')
    ->leftJoin('orders.payment', 'payment')
    ->leftJoin('orders.paymentInstances', 'paymentInstances')
    ->leftJoin('SapExport\Models\PaymentPayPal', 'paymentPayPal', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'orders.number = paymentPayPal.ordernumber AND payment.name = \'paypal\'')
    ->leftJoin('orders.billing', 'billing')
    ->leftJoin('billing.country', 'billingCountry')
    ->leftJoin('orders.shipping', 'shipping')
    ->leftJoin('shipping.country', 'shippingCountry')
    ->leftJoin('orders.paymentStatus', 'paymentStatus');

$builder->where('orders.cleared = ' . Status::PAYMENT_STATE_COMPLETELY_PAID)
    ->andWhere($builder->expr()->notIn('orders.id', $this->getSapExportIdsQuery()->getDQL()));

$builder->orderBy('orders.id', 'DESC');
```

The subselect query in `where` clause:

```
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->select([
    'sapExport.id'
]);
$builder->from('SapExport\Models\SapExport', 'sapExport');
```

If I hydrate it to array it outputs something like this (json encoded data):

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 10353,
      "number": "650004023",
      "customerId": 4235,
      "status": 0,
      "cleared": 12,
      "paymentId": 7,
      "dispatchId": 10,
      "partnerId": "",
      "shopId": 1,
      "invoiceAmount": 99.95,
      "invoiceAmountNet": 83.99,
      "invoiceShipping": 0,
      "invoiceShippingNet": 0,
      ...
      "details": [
        {
          ...
        }
      ],
      "paymentInstances": [
        {
          ...
        }
      ],
      "billing": {
        ...
      },
      "shipping": {
        ...
      },
      "paymentStatus": {
        ...
      }
    }
  ],
  {
  "0": {
  "id": 251,
  "ordernumber": "650004023",
  "referenceNumber": "34TEST",
  "instructionType": "TEST",
  "bankName": "bank name",
  "accountHolder": "PayPal Europe",
  "iban": "DEXXXXXX",
  "amountValue": "99.95",
  "amountCurrency": "EUR",
  "paymentDueDate": {
  "date": "2018-01-31 00:00:00.000000",
  "timezone_type": 3,
  "timezone": "Europe\/Berlin"
  },
  "links": "[{\"href\":\"https://www.example.com\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]"
  },
  "id": 7,
  "name": "paypal",
  "description": "PayPal",
  "action": "payment_paypal",
  "pluginId": 64
  }
]
```

Needed result / Expected result:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 10353,
      "number": "650004023",
      "customerId": 4235,
      "status": 0,
      "cleared": 12,
      "paymentId": 7,
      "dispatchId": 10,
      "partnerId": "",
      "shopId": 1,
      "invoiceAmount": 99.95,
      "invoiceAmountNet": 83.99,
      "invoiceShipping": 0,
      "invoiceShippingNet": 0,
      ...
      "details": [
        {
          ...
        }
      ],
      "paymentInstances": [
        {
          ...
        }
      ],
      "billing": {
        ...
      },
      "shipping": {
        ...
      },
      "paymentStatus": {
        ...
      },
      "paymentPayPal": {
        "id": 251,
        "ordernumber": "650004023",
        "referenceNumber": "34TEST",
        "instructionType": "TEST",
        "bankName": "bank name",
        "accountHolder": "PayPal Europe",
        "iban": "DEXXXXXX",
        "amountValue": "99.95",
        "amountCurrency": "EUR",
        "paymentDueDate": {
          "date": "2018-01-31 00:00:00.000000",
          "timezone_type": 3,
          "timezone": "Europe\/Berlin"
        },
        "links": "[{\"href\":\"https://www.example.com\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]"
      },
      "payment": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "paypal",
        "description": "PayPal",
        "action": "payment_paypal",
        "pluginId": 64
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

If I execucte the SQL on the database, the result set is as expected. So, it seems to be a strange doctrine entity mapping.

**Edit: For clearance to my actually problem, that I have:** The entity **`payment` is not on the main entity**, called `orders`. It gets an own object, right next to `orders` in the array result set. So, we have two issues there:

1. `payment` is an object, not an array.
2. It gets an own entry, but it should appear under the `orders` entry in result set.

Also, **`paymentPayPal` entity does completely not appear** in the result set. **But it should, because I selected it** as well.

**Edit 2**: This is the resulting **DQL** Query (please note that I reduced `details` entity a bit, since I don't need all columns of it):

> SELECT orders, details.id, details.articleId, details.number,
>   details.articleNumber, details.price, details.quantity,
>   details.articleName, details.mode, details.esdArticle, details.unit,
>   details.packUnit, payment.id, payment.name, payment.description,
>   payment.action, payment.pluginId, paymentInstances, shipping, billing,
>   billingCountry, shippingCountry, paymentPayPal, paymentStatus FROM
>   Shopware\Models\Order\Order orders LEFT JOIN orders.details details
>   LEFT JOIN orders.payment payment LEFT JOIN orders.paymentInstances
>   paymentInstances LEFT JOIN SapExport\Models\PaymentPayPal
>   paymentPayPal WITH orders.number = paymentPayPal.ordernumber AND
>   payment.name = 'paypal' LEFT JOIN orders.billing billing LEFT JOIN
>   billing.country billingCountry LEFT JOIN orders.shipping shipping LEFT
>   JOIN shipping.country shippingCountry LEFT JOIN orders.paymentStatus
>   paymentStatus WHERE orders.cleared = 12 AND orders.id NOT IN(SELECT
>   sapExport.id FROM SapExport\Models\SapExport sapExport) ORDER BY
>   orders.id DESC

**Edit 3**: The query works fine, if I do not leftJoin the paypal table. I need this table to get additional informations, if the customer has choosen paypal as the payment type for his oder her order. But only for this type I need those additional informations. As far as I know, leftJoin should do the trick. Because, if it's not paypal, it should join an empty record set with `null`ed columns. But I am wondering why Doctrine behaves this way, the SQL Query pendant works well...

Comment: are you looking for somthing like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990352/mysql-multiple-left-joins

Comment: if youre using entities with proper relationships setup, then why not just use getters and setters to retrieve the data you need?  Let doctrine do the heavy lifting. eg: `Order::getDetails`. If you need lots of info, create a `toArray` method and dump in what you need.

Comment: @NishitManjarawala Yeah, every sql aggregate function needs a group by statement. But I don't have this in my query. However, I tried it by adding an `group by orders.id`. Doesn't change anything.

@DevDonkey I don't have properly setup entities, because I can't alter Shopware's core models. That's the point why I need such a complex query. Ok, well, I am able to alter Shopware's core models, but it well be gone after each update.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use QueryBuilder helper method **addSelect** with leftJoin.

Personally I never use it before, but I known it exists and it can be useful for you IMO.

Some docs are [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) and [here](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/joins-reduce-queries) is some Doctrine tutorial.

Comment: Ok, and how it helps me?

Comment: If I good understund, it add your select (of join) into existing in query selects and array hydrate should looks similar you expected.

Comment: Well, that's basically the same as I already did. When you use the select method on `QueryBuilder` with an array as parameter, it selects you exactly those fields you specified in the array. And as far as I know, the `QueryBuilder` methods always return the instance of itself. So, as you called it "the existing query".

Comment: in your example, you have $builder->select(['sapExport.id']); and as a result {...} [0] => {}. Try to use addSelec instead of just select. If you have proper left join for sapExport - it should works as result {.... [sapExport} => {} }. ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I edited my question. Please have a look (and please tell me, if I am wrong).

Comment: Yep. I misunderstund you. Now is clear. You use two different models class, probably there is a problem SapExport\Models\PaymentPayPal for leftJoin in first query but SapExport\Models\SapExport for subquery. You always can check you querybuilder by $qb->getDql(); for test if this simillar for your working SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166951/discussion-between-slawitdev-and-alpham8).